# Upload files in chunks via WebDav

Tags: c#, file-upload, webdav

We developed a asp.net web application which uses an ashx handler to do partial file Uploads. A user can select files via a silverlight control and the control starts a Post HttpWebRequest to the ashx handler and transmits the file in smaller chunks (via HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream) so that the silverlight control can Display a Progress bar.

Now we want to expand on this solution to support Uploads to WebDAV Folders.
So the main question is: Can this "chunk-wise" upload be done via WebDAV at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebDAV protocol is an extension of HTTP protocol, so all HTTP features will work with it. The best way is to calculate a file size before upload - this will allow to *draw* a progress bar easily.

Another option is to use Content-Range header that allows to send data in chunks, but this will result in one HTTP GET request per chunk.

JFYI: our [WebDAVBlackbox](http://eldos.com/sbb/desc-webdav.php) allows to use all WebDAV features from Silverlight relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that if you keep the connection open that does the PUT request, you can keep on sending it data.. you have to make sure you're not timing out though. One thing that may be problematic, is that many DAV servers need to know the full content-length when the PUT starts.

Otherwise, there is no standard to keep on appending to a file, split out over multiple HTTP requests; but maybe your server has a non-standard extension for it.. [SabreDAV](https://code.google.com/p/sabredav/) does.

Comment: I'm using IIS 7 as webdav folder host